# PHPMailer sent message, but returned CLIENT/SERVER dialog to browser

Tags: php, email, localhost, phpmailer

So I've searched Google and Stackoverflow and I'm a bit surprised I could not find this problem.

I'm using XAMPP/localhost and PHPmailer sending an email to my yahoo account using my gmail email account.  Everything worked perfectly with the email being send and received, including a sample attachment.

The problem is my browser is displaying what appears to be a dialog of the SERVER/CLIENT for each step of the behind the scene processing just before the "Sent successful" message.

Sample output here:

```
2014-02-04 05:44:36 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 mx.google.com
ESMTP xv2sm62192389pbb.39 - gsmtp
2014-02-04 05:44:36 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2014-02-04 05:44:36 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-mx.google.com at your service, [171.6.91.113] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250 CHUNKING
2014-02-04 05:44:36 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2014-02-04 05:44:36 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
2014-02-04 05:44:36 CLIENT -> SERVER: a2hyZng0NDRAZ21haWwuY29t
2014-02-04 05:44:37 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2014-02-04 05:44:37 CLIENT -> SERVER: RnV0dXJlMTA= 
2014-02-04 05:44:38 SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 2.7.0 Accepted 
.
.  25 more lines of this stuff
.
2014-02-04 05:44:40 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 
2014-02-04 05:44:40 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection xv2sm62192389pbb.39 - gsmtp 
Message has been sent
```

I put line breaks in to make it more readable, but it comes out as one long string on the screen.

Here is the code.  How do I suppress this output?

```
require_once "../phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php";

$mail = new \PHPMailer(true); 

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port       = 465;
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Username   = "xxx@gmail.com";
$mail->Password   = "xxx";
$mail->SetFrom('xxx@gmail.com', 'Randy S');
$mail->WordWrap = 50;

$mail->AddAddress('xxx@yahoo.com', 'Randy');
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Test Subject';
$mail->Body     = "Hi! \n\n This is my first e-mail sent through PHPMailer."; 
$mail->AddAttachment('upload/names.txt');      // attachment

if(!$mail->Send()){
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo; 
} else {
echo "Message has been sent";
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this is a duplicate.  I used different words to search and finally found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117816/why-is-php-mailer-printing-mimeheader-to-screen-after-send  Zero '0' or 'false' will work for the SMTPDebug parameter.

Comment: When you download class libraries, read the readme...that info was very basic and in there.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Comment or remove this line or set it to `0`:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
```

It's used to display errors and messages.

From the PHPMailer site:

> $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;  // enables SMTP debug information (for
>   testing)
>                           // 1 = errors and messages
>                           // 2 = messages only

Comment: Thank you sir..  Your answer made my day.. Thax

Answer (score 2):

`SMTPDebug` defined at `class.phpmailer.php` as below. According to this, you should initialize `SMTPDebug` as 0. Thus, any command or data messages won't be shown. Also, you can view error message when error occurred by using ErrorInfo field of PHPMailer class.

```
/**
 * SMTP class debug output mode.
 * Debug output level.
 * Options:
 * * `0` No output
 * * `1` Commands
 * * `2` Data and commands
 * * `3` As 2 plus connection status
 * * `4` Low-level data output
 * @type integer
 * @see SMTP::$do_debug
 */
public $SMTPDebug = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem,
add

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = false;
```

in the mail sending script, after

```
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
```

It will work